# Create ts from data frame and decompose using STL

Tags: r, stl, time-series

I'm new to R and in the process of creating my first time series analysis.
My first step is to convert the data (data frame) to a time series and:

This is the data before conversion:

```
           Date    Value Season
1576 2017-01-30 45330.34      0
1604 2017-02-27 43757.68      0
1693 2017-03-30 50092.90      1
1723 2017-04-29 39405.65      0
1812 2017-05-30 42031.80      0
1842 2017-06-29 40008.67      0
```

This is the format:

```
> str(mth3)
'data.frame':   66 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Date   : Date, format: "2012-01-30" "2012-02-28" ...
 $ Value  : num  40222 43437 46047 33813 35757 ...
 $ Season : int  0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 2 ...
```

When I convert the data using this code:

```
mth4 <- ts(mth3, frequency=12, start=c(2012,1), end=c(2017,6))
```

Then the data looks like this:

```
          Date  Value        Season
Jan 2017 17196 45330.34      0
Feb 2017 17224 43757.68      0
Mar 2017 17255 50092.90      1
Apr 2017 17285 39405.65      0
May 2017 17316 42031.80      0
Jun 2017 17346 40008.67      0
```

The format of the data in `mth4` is:

```
-Series [1:66, 1:3] from 2012 to 2017: 15369 15398 15429 15459 15490 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "Date" "Value" "Season"
```

When decomposing data into trend, seasonality and random behaviour

```
mth_stl <- stl(mth4, s.window="periodic")
```

This error is the result:

```
only univariate series are allowed
```

My guess is that I'm doing something wrong on the formatting, but I do not know why and have used a considerable amount of time searching this forum.

Comment: You may need `xts` i.e. `library(xts); mth4 <- xts(mth3[-1], order.by = as.Date(mth3$Date))`  For more info, you can check a recent post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45296981/csv-data-convert-to-xts/45297080#45297080)

Comment: @akrun - Thank you for your comment. I've change the structure and the date variable is now excluded, but the error is still the same. Unfortunately. > str(mth4)
An ‘xts’ object on 2012-01-30/2017-06-29 containing:
  Data: num [1:66, 1:2] 40222 43437 46047 33813 35757 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "Value" "Season"
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need xts, despite the comment and my affinity for the package. :)

The problem is in the error message, "only univariate series are allowed".  Your `mth4` object is a multivariate timeseries.  `stl()` only accepts a univariate series, so you need to extract the `Value` column to pass to `stl()`.

```
R> mth_stl <- stl(mth4[,"Value"], s.window="periodic")
R> str(mth_stl)
List of 8
 $ time.series: Time-Series [1:66, 1:3] from 2012 to 2017: 621 175 425 -104 2528 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "seasonal" "trend" "remainder"
 $ weights    : num [1:66] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ call       : language stl(x = mth4[, "Value"], s.window = "periodic")
 $ win        : Named num [1:3] 661 19 13
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "s" "t" "l"
 $ deg        : Named int [1:3] 0 1 1
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "s" "t" "l"
 $ jump       : Named num [1:3] 67 2 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "s" "t" "l"
 $ inner      : int 2
 $ outer      : int 0
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "stl"
```

You also don't need to include the `Date` column from your data.frame in the `ts` object.  `ts` objects have an implicit date based on their `start`, `end`, and `frequency` components.  So you could create your `ts` object with:

```
mth4 <- ts(mth3[, c("Value", "Season")], frequency=12, start=c(2012,1), end=c(2017,6))
```